# Die Roll Probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

If Zachary rolls a fair die five times, what is the probability that the sum of his five rolls is 20?

1st I did:

Patterns of 5 that can give us 20

66611, 66521, 65531, 65522, 64442, 64433, 64415,

Where do we go from here?

Comment: The list is incomplete. It is missing many entries, Like $55532$, $44444$, others. Once you have a complete list, we need for each pattern the number of orders it can occur in.

Comment: Is there any easier way to create a complete list besides sitting here and just plugging in 5 numbers that = 20 perhaps using GCF or GCM ?

Comment: I can't think of anything simple. One can use generating functions, but that would take a long time to explain. It might be more efficient to use the easy sum probabilities for $2$ dice to get **all** the sum probabilities for $3$, then all sum probabilities for $4$ then all the sum probabilities for $5$. Overall not a fun project.

Comment: No a discrete math course.  Hmm it seems there should be an easier way to find the patterns I need.

Comment: @user85542 Sorry, I meant if that class was covering generating functions.

Comment: Also, since you recently asked for "algorithm help", are you supposed to write an algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: No your answered helped me answer this thank you.

Comment: It doesn't make any **real** difference in this case, but note that the number of ways to get $20$ is the same as the number of ways to ger $(5)(6)-20=10$. Symmetry is our friend.

Comment: @user85542 You can also use the PIE pretty directly, esp with Andre's observation that we just want a sum of 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you know generating functions.

We are interested in the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the expansion $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^5$.

This is equivalent to the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in the expansion $\left( \frac{1- x^6}{1-x} \right)^5 $

The numerator is easily evaluated as

$$ 1- - 5 x^{6} + 10 x^{12} - 10x^{18} + 5 x^{24} - x^{30} $$

The denominator is

$$ \sum x^i {i+4 \choose 4} $$

Hence, the answer is

$$ 10 \times {7 \choose 4} - 5 \times {13 \choose 4} + 1 \times {19 \choose 4} $$

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use generating functions, use recursion and a spreadsheet like the following , where the number of ways of getting a score of $s$ with $d$ dice is the sum of the ways of getting a score of $s-1,s-2,s-3,s-4$ or $s-5$ with $d-1$ dice (starting with there being $1$ way of getting a score of $0$ with $0$ dice).

```
Dice    0   1   2   3   4   5
    ---------------------------
Score
0       1   0   0   0   0   0
1       0   1   0   0   0   0
2       0   1   1   0   0   0
3       0   1   2   1   0   0
4       0   1   3   3   1   0
5       0   1   4   6   4   1
6       0   1   5   10  10  5
7       0   0   6   15  20  15
8       0   0   5   21  35  35
9       0   0   4   25  56  70
10      0   0   3   27  80  126
11      0   0   2   27  104 205
12      0   0   1   25  125 305
13      0   0   0   21  140 420
14      0   0   0   15  146 540
15      0   0   0   10  140 651
16      0   0   0   6   125 735
17      0   0   0   3   104 780
18      0   0   0   1   80  780
19      0   0   0   0   56  735
20      0   0   0   0   35  651
21      0   0   0   0   20  540
22      0   0   0   0   10  420
23      0   0   0   0   4   305
24      0   0   0   0   1   205
25      0   0   0   0   0   126
26      0   0   0   0   0   70
27      0   0   0   0   0   35
28      0   0   0   0   0   15
29      0   0   0   0   0   5
30      0   0   0   0   0   1
```